# Connection between properties of taylor series and the function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Assuming I have a function $f(x)$ which at least for some $-R<x<R$ can be expanded in taylor series

$$
    f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

are there any known connections between properties of the series $\{c_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and properties of the function itself?

I have not seen any in textbooks and it seems odd given the importance of taylor series.

The kind of connection of properties I'm talking about would be: *if $\{c_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is periodic then the function is periodic* (I know this one is incorrect, but just to illustrate).

Comment: "If $(c_n)_n$ only has finitely many non-zero terms, then $f$ is a polynomial?" (on $(a,b)$)

Comment: If $c_n=0$ for all odd $n$ ($1,3,5,\ldots$), then $f$ is an even function (that is, $f(-x)=f(x)$. Similarly, if $c_n=0$ for all even $n$ ($0,2,4,\cdots$), then $f$ is an odd function (that is, $f(-x)=-f(x)$).

Comment: When you say "can be expanded in taylor series for some $x$", do you mean "in a neighborhood of some $x$" ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: As stated, the series is expanded about $x=0$ and converges at least in the interval $(a,b)$. Of course, one may assume this interval of convergence is of the form $(-r,r)$ since the center is $0$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM yes, I've corrected the post, thanks

Comment: Anything from asymptotes? Like "if $ c_n \propto 1/n^\alpha$ as $n\to\infty$ then..."